# LG G2 rooting error

Tags: rooting, root-access, lg-g2

I'm rooting LG G2 (for Verizon) following this instruction.
http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2448887

While I'm running root.bat, it seems to freeze showing that
'Looking for device'.
I closed the command window and re-ran root.bat but always the same result.
So I cannot proceed anymore.
What should I do?

Comment: Did you performed the steps properly by enable Usb debugging and other instructions? If that post is not clear to you a blog is [here](http://blog.laptopmag.com/root-lg-g2)